# typecast problem with List class

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the bug here?

```
private void LoadUsers(List<long> uids, EventUser.EventUserStatus eventUserStatus, IList<user> chkfriends)
{
    foreach (var f in chkfriends) 
    {
      long l = f.uid; <-- fails
       if (uids.Contains(l)) do it!
    }
```

Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'long?' to 'long'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f.uid` is presumably [`long?`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) - in which case just:

```
long l = f.uid.Value;
```

This assumes that the value of `uid` isn't empty. If there might be `null` ids in the set, then perhaps:

```
if(f.uid != null && uids.Contains(f.uid.Value)) {
    // do it!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long l = f.uid.Value;
```

The bug is that `f.uid` is [`Nullable<long>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) and you are trying to assign it to `long`.

Answer (score 0):

f.uid is nullable long (`System.Nullable<long>`), so you cannot assign it to a long.

Try:

```
long? l = f.uid;
```

Or perhaps:

```
if ( f.uid == null ) 
    throw new NullReferenceException("Uid cannot be null");
long l = f.uid.Value;
```

It might be an error situation if the uid is null, in that case it would be appropiate to throw an exception. You can [read more about nullable types here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Your local variable `l` is of type `long` while the field or property  `user.uid` seems to be of type `Nullable<long>` (a.k.a. `long?`) - therefore the assignment is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

uid is nullable so change your statement to this one and it should work.

```
long l = f.uid ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

one more choice.

```
if (!f.uid.HasValue)   
    throw new NullReferenceException("Uid cannot be null");  
long l = f.uid.Value;
```